# Is it possible to add a header to one specific $resource request in Angular JS?

Tags: angularjs

In one place in my code where I use a `$save` action I want to add a specific header.

- I *don't* want this to apply to *every* time I use save in other places in the app, so I don't want to add the header to the `$resource` declaration itself.
- I *don't* want the header applied to any other requests so I don't want to use `$http.defaults.headers`.

Is there a way I can do this without just giving up and using `$http`?

Comment: Is it possible you could achieve the desired result using [Request Interceptors](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$http)? When the desired request is issued you could then add your header there.

Comment: It's kind of difficult to tell from an interceptor whether it's necessary. This happens in one very specific context. I guess I could do something horrible like put a flag in the `$rootScope`.

Comment: Yes, it is not ideal. But it does keep you from setting the header for all requests.

Comment: Just use $http for that request...

Answer (score 0):

Yes, in the [ngResource docs](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource.%24resource) you can read:

> $resource(url[, paramDefaults][, actions]);
>
> > ...
> >
> > **actions** -> Hash with declaration of custom action that should extend the default set of resource actions. The declaration should be created in the format of $http.config:
> >
> > `{action1: {method:?, params:?, isArray:?, headers:?, ...}`

Just pass the headers that you want there, as a object, in your action definition.

Comment: But that would apply to *every* call to `$save`. See first bullet point in the question.

Comment: @PirateRob Cant you just create a new actions, let's say, `saveWithHeaders` and use it when you need?